# setlocale error with chroot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, chroot

I have created a chroot jail and when I log in I get a bash warning `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

I tried to google the error, but wasn't able to find a solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing `/usr/lib/locale` inside your chroot.  Try copying them into place from your non-chroot'd `/usr/lib/locale` or chroot with `LANG=C`.

Comment: Chrooting with `LC_ALL=C` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

While Travis Campbell's answer is certainly very valid, I found an alternative solution on my Debian Buster chroot that probably also works on Ubuntu.
In the **chrooted environment**:

```
apt update
apt install locales
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

I then selected the locale that the error message complained about (`en_US.UTF-8`).
Exiting and going back to the chrooted environment doesn't display the error message anymore.